# Stubbing Backbone Class constructor with Jasmin and Sinon

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette, sinon

In the following module:

```
@APP.module "LeftSidebar", (LeftSidebar, APP, Backbone, Marionette) ->

API =
  initialize: ()->
    @controller = new LeftSidebar.Controller

LeftSidebar.addInitializer ()->
  API.initialize()
```

... I want to test whether `LeftSidebar.Controller` gets initialized when `APP.LeftSidebar.addInitializer()` is called. I have tried to with the following spec, but `@spy.calledWithNew()` returns false:

```
describe "LeftSidebar app", ->
  describe "initialization", ->
    beforeEach ->
      @spy = sinon.spy(APP.LeftSidebar, "Controller")
      APP.LeftSidebar.addInitializer()

  it "initializes LeftSidebar.Controller", ->
    expect(@spy.calledWithNew()).toBeTruthy()
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Spy on `initialize` instead.
2. You're missing the initialization to be tested, add it to the test.

```coffeescript
describe "LeftSidebar app", ->
  describe "initialization", ->
    beforeEach ->
      @spy = sinon.spy(@controller, "initialize")
      // APP.LeftSidebar.addInitializer() // this does nothing, drop it

  it "initializes LeftSidebar.Controller", ->
    new @controller();
    expect(@controller.initialize.calledOnce).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: That will do it... Thanks for the simple and correct answer!